# HTMLEditFormat and take care of line breaks

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, line-breaks

I have some text that I get from my database and want to insert into an HTML page. 
I'm using `HTMLEditFormat` to take care of special characters like '<' etc...

Problem: When this is displayed in the browser all the line breaks are gone. Is there a special formatting function in CF that will automatically replace all line breaks with the correct HTML tag?

Comment: You can use https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForHTML

Comment: Anit, how does that solve the OP's question?  AFAIK, encodeForHTML doesn't not add any markup to the string.

Comment: @AnitKumar EncodeForHTML is only for CF 10, no?

Comment: ParagraphFormat() might be what you want.

Comment: `HTMLEditFormat()` is deprecated in ColdFusion 11, btw. Yu may want to consider `xmlFormat()`

Answer (score 5):

HTMLEditFormat() will escape any HTML markup, but the line breaks are a separate issue. By definition, line breaks in HTML don't affect rendering.  Same as multiple spaces and tabs.

If the text in question was collected in a textarea, one option is to output it in a disabled textarea, which will render the line breaks and spaces as they were typed.

My usual approach to to replace new lines with a 
 tag and tabs with 5  's.  The paragraphFormat() function will handle new lines.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e24.html

Or this function from CFLib will also handle the tabs for you:
http://www.cflib.org/udf/ParagraphFormat2